# Gboard suddenly changes keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, 7.0-nougat, gboard

I'm using Gboard on my Android 7.0 phone in Skype. I'm using the English (UK) keyboard with QWERTZ and QWERTY layout. My problem is that when I set QWERTY the keyboard layout suddenly changes to QWERTZ after some time.

How can I prevent this random changes in the keyboard layout?

Comment: Does this happens only when you are in Skype app ?

Comment: @PuspamAdak I recognized it only in Skype app because I'm most of the time using this app.

Comment: Then that issue might be caused by that app, because I had also updated the Google Keyboard (Gboard), but till now I haven't faced any such problem.

Comment: I have also noticed that in WhatsApp, the default emojis in the keyboard gets replaced by different ones. So, these things happens because some apps try to modify the input methods.